# latex .bst style

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to submit to Journal of Labour Economics and they give a link with bibliography style, but they don't say what style it is.  I am having trouble finding a .bst file that replicates their examples.  Does anyone know what style this is or what .bst file I need?

http://www.jstor.org/page/journal/jlaboreconomics/instruct.html

ournals
Costa, Dora L. 2000. The wage and the length of the work day. Journal of Labor Economics 18 (January): 156-81.

Costa, Dora L. 2000. The wage and the length of the work day. Journal of Labor Economics 18, no. 1:156-81.

Costa, Dora L. 2000. The wage and the length of the work day. Journal of Labor Economics 18:156-81.

Costa, Dora L. 2000. The wage and the length of the work day. Journal of Labor Economics 18, no. 1, pt. 2:S156-S181.

Costa, Dora L. 2000. The wage and the length of the work day. Journal of Labor Economics 18, suppl.: S156-S181.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Reading the instructions to authors I find: _The preferred format for submitting manuscripts online is Microsoft Word (.doc files)._ so I'd guess 'They do not use a `.bst` file' is the answer!

Comment: this is an author-year style, so you might try `natbib`.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a .bst file that matches these guidelines as closely as possible. It's available at https://github.com/tyleransom/jolebib/ (file: jole.bst).